# Android, Renamed image file not shown at phone gallery folder

Tags: android, file-rename

In my phone apps, I tried to rename the existed image file to another name. Everything runs accordingly after execute the code. However I don't know why the renamed image file is shown on SD card file manager but didn't shown on "my_folder" in my phone gallery. Please help me to check if there is mistake on my coding. Appreciate your help.

```
    String original="image.jpg";
    String latest="lucky.jpg";

    private void saveImage(String latest, String original)
    {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir=new File(root + "/my_folder");
        if (myDir.exists())
        {
            File from = new File(myDir, original + ".jpg");
            File to=new File(myDir, latest + ".jpg");
            if (from.exists())
            {
                from.renameTo(to);
                Uri contentUri=Uri.fromFile(from);
                Intent mediaScanIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the media scanner to scan the "from" path. Consider also telling it to scan the "to" path.

You could do both in one operation [using `scanFile()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29).

Comment: Can you teach me the format to write scanFile() based on my coding? Appreciate your help